# Let $p$ be an odd prime, and denote $A_p$ the integer for which $1 + \frac{1}{2} + \cdots + \frac{1}{p-1} = \frac{A_p}{(p-1)!}$. Prove that $p|A_p$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

Let $p$ be an odd prime, and denote by $A_p$ the integer for which
$$1 + \frac{1}{2} + \cdots + \frac{1}{p-1} = \frac{A_p}{(p-1)!}$$
prove that $p|A_p$.

Answer (score 5):

You have to show that $(p-1)!\displaystyle \sum_{k=1}^{p-1} k^{-1}=0$ in $\mathbb{F}_p.$ Inversion simply permutes the units, so $\displaystyle\sum_{k=1}^{p-1} k^{-1}= \sum_{k=1}^{p-1} k= p(p-1)/2 =0$ so the result follows.

Comment: Not sure I understand that

Comment: @David I used somewhat advanced tools for this problem that are certainly not required, but are useful. Geoff gave a hint for a totally elementary approach, and if you want to see it in full detail it is claim 1 [here](http://math.uci.edu/~tchoi/notes/wolstenholme.pdf). You can also get an introduction to the method I used [here](http://projectpen.files.wordpress.com/2009/04/pen-a23-a24-version-edited2.pdf). Feel free to ask anything if you have any more questions, and sorry for the lateness of my reply.

Answer (score 2):

Another approach is to rewrite the sum of reciprocals as $\sum_{i=1}^{\frac{p-1}{2}} (\frac{1}{i} + \frac{1}{p-i}) = \sum_{i=1}^{\frac{p-1}{2}} \frac{p}{i(p-i)}.$